# Adding functionality to Grails restfulcontroller

Tags: rest, grails

I'm having a very simple restful controller, which looks like this:

```
class PersonController extends RestfulController<Person> {

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    PersonController() {
        super(Person)
    }
}
```

However, now I want to add a search option to this. What is the Grails way of making this possible?

I thought of adding the following:

```
def search(Map params) {
    println params
}
```

But that makes Grails (2.3) crash (| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)).

So what is the right way of adding this? I'm looking for some solution which I can call using `http://localhost:8080/foo/person/search?q=erik`

This is my UrlMappings:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }


    "/rest/persons"(resources:'Person')
```

I've changed the above to:

```
def search() {
    println params
}
```

And that doesn't give the compilation error anymore, but I still get this error:

```
TypeMismatchException occurred when processing request: [GET] /declaratie-web/rest/medicaties/search - parameters:
q: erik
Provided id of the wrong type for class nl.Person. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class nl.Person. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
```

I also found out that it doesn't matter how I call the controller:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/person/search?q=erik
http://localhost:8080/foo/person/search222?q=erik
http://localhost:8080/foo/person/search39839329?q=erik
```

All fails with the above error, so it seems my method is ignored (maybe caused by my URLmapping?)

Comment: Did you try to leave away the params argument of the search action?

Comment: Hi aioslos, thanks for the hint. I tried that, and Grails starts up now, but it doesn't work. I also added the UrlMapping, maybe that's the cause? What I found out is that the controller is completely ignoring the 'search' part right now, I can replace it by a dummy word and it will still give an error.

Comment: /foo/person/search... does not follow the REST model and you shouldn't use a `RestfulController` if you don't want a REST api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really aren't being RESTful by doing that. `q` should just be a parameter for the index action. You can override that method to include your functionality.

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def c = Person.createCriteria()
    def results = c.list(params) {
       //Your criteria here with params.q
    }
    respond results, model:[personCount: results.totalCount]
}
```

Comment: Ah, sure, that makes so much sense! Thanks so much for helping out here, that's of course the solution.

Comment: You can add String q to the input parameters of the action instead of doing `params.q` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

@james-kleeh solution is right, but you can do it more clean by override the `listAllResources` method which is called by `index`

```
@Override
protected List<Payment> listAllResources(Map params) {
    Person.createCriteria().list(params) {
        // Your criteria here with params.q
    }
}
```