# Fetching & Updating lazy-loaded many-many fields in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, spring-data-rest

How do I **correctly** expose **lazy-loaded** many-many fields so that users can `GET`/`PATCH`/`POST`/`DELETE` many-many entity relationships in Spring Data REST?

For example, given a `Student` entity and `Teacher` entity bound by a many to many relationship, with the following POJOs:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher { // owner of bidirectional relationship
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "teacher_student",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    private Set<Student> students;

    // Constructor, getters/setters...
}

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Teacher> teachers;

    // Constructor, getters/setters...
}
```

The entities are given repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "teacher")
public interface TeacherRepository extends CrudRepository<Teacher, int> {}

// similar repository for student
```

When I send a `GET` to localhost:8080/teacher, I get:

```
"_embedded": {
    "teacher": [
        {
        "name": "Bill Billie",
        "_links": {
            "self": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/teacher/1" },
            "teacher": { ... },
            "students": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/teacher/1/students" }
        }},
        (more teachers here...)
    ]
}
...
```

**BUT**, when I try a `GET` to http://localhost:8080/teacher/1/students, I get a **404 Not Found**, even though the teacher "Bill Billie" *does* have a student associated with him in the database.

Interestingly, if I change the `FetchType` to `FetchType.EAGER`, everything works fine and I *can* perform the expected `GET`, `PATCH`, etc. What gives? Is this a bug, perhaps, or am I screwing something up?

**tl;dr Many-many relations are not correctly exposed with lazy fetching, but work fine with eager fetching. How can I get lazy fetching to work with it?**

**Edit**: If it matters, I am using Spring 4.2.6 with Spring Boot 1.3.5, and OpenJPA 2.4.1 as my JPA provider.

Comment: This is likely to be quite a complicated issue; especially since you are using OpenJPA instead of say, Hibernate, which is probably better known. If you provide a working example project that demonstrates the issue, you're much more likely to get a resolution.

Comment: @WillFaithfull that's fair. I might give that a shot and try to have a working example, though given the amount of dependencies and custom configuration, that would be challenging. Oh, the joys of custom business needs.

Comment: Try to make the most minimal example possible. It doesn't need to resemble your domain model, just reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you please share logging information for this request?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I am not sure why it isn't auto-fetching someone more experienced would have to ask that, but you can specify a manual fetch with HQL's join fetch  for each query.

```
select x from X left join fetch x.y y
```

After getting this working you can override your get statement with a specifically created controller as described here: [Spring Data REST: Override repository method on the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773171/spring-data-rest-override-repository-method-on-the-controller)

Only other option I think might be worth trying is adding an @Lazy annotation on your Spring-data repository.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I could get it to work if I manually write all the queries and override the `find` methods, but that would mostly defeat the point of using Spring JPA and Data REST in the first place. I'd prefer to keep that as a last resort. Oh and the `@Lazy` annotation doesn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to you for the helpful response, even though it didn't exactly solve the problem I was facing. Still looking for more answers.

Comment: Thanks,  When I get a chance I will try and setup a test project and see if I can run some debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your RestResources transactional.

Annotate with `@Transactional`

Comment: Can you please paste your TransactionManager bean here. Just bean declaration from context xml

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```